# scrapy error ImportError: No module named scrapy.cmdline

Tags: python, scrapy

I've some problem with Scrapy on my mac, I checked many website to find an answer but I didn't find any good one.

Here's my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
ImportError: No module named scrapy.cmdline
```

I actually have Scrapy 1.5.0 ,Twisted 17.9.0, lxml 4.2.0

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Seems like there some version missmatching going on. could you post results of `which scrapy` command?

Comment: this is my the path of scrapy  /usr/local/bin/scrapy

Comment: There's something definitely wrong with your python/scrapy setup. Maybe try to just `sudo pip install scrapy --upgrade`?

Comment: I was already upgrade scrapy. I use python 3.6.2. Is there any problem with this version?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some mismatch in Scrapy installation, please note that path to Scrapy cli command in error message is `/usr/bin/scrapy` while you told that your path to scrapy is `/usr/local/bin/scrapy` so either add `/usr/local/bin/` to your PATH like this (from cli/in .rc file):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

or reinstall Scrapy.

Comment: When I add PATH and re-establish the soft link of scrapy, scrapy has become normal.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To me, the problem was that one of the latest MacOS updates had upgraded Python, which seems to have crashed a virtual environment I had created for this project.

So basically I've removed my virtual environment: `cd /to/my/project && rm -rf  venv` (assuming your virtual env folder was "venv")

And re-created it:

- `python3 -m venv venv` to "install" the virtual env
- `source venv/bin/activate` to activate the venv. If you run `which python` it should point to a python executable within the venv folder
- re-install your dependencies via `pip install -r requirements.txt`

After that, everything works again :) (at least for me)